# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < Using jqgrid and MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

JQGrid is not displaying an error in the form when submitting incorrect data.
It works on my local machine but not in production. It used to work in prod but I've made a couple of changes in the last couple of months and am not sure which change broke it.
I am using JQGrid 4.4.1, jquery 1.7.2 and MVC 4. The error in the browser is showing the following

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery%20-1.7.2.min.js:3
e.extend.parseJSON jquery%20-1.7.2.min.js:3
editItems.errorTextFormat WaterReadingCapture:1291
$.extend.complete jquery.jqGrid.src.js:7572
o jquery%20-1.7.2.min.js:3
p.fireWith jquery%20-1.7.2.min.js:3
w jquery%20-1.7.2.min.js:10
d jquery%20-1.7.2.min.js:10
```

**EDIT**

This is what I am getting from the server.
an Html page with this in the body. I also upgraded RazorEngine. Could the problem be on the server and nothing to do with the jquery and jqgrid? BUT I copied the whole site from prod and ran it on my local machine and it worked.

```
<h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
  <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
```

WaterReadingCapture

```
 errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                      return '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>' +
                     "<strong>" + $.parseJSON(data.responseText).Message + "<strong>";
                   },
```

JQGrid

```
if(Status != "success") {
    ret[0] = false;
    ret[1] = $($t).triggerHandler("jqGridAddEditErrorTextFormat", [data, frmoper]);
    if ($.isFunction(rp_ge[$t.p.id].errorTextFormat)) {
        ret[1] = rp_g
    e[$t.p.id].errorTextFormat.call($t, data);
    } else {
        ret[1] = Status + " Status: '" + data.statusText + "'. Error code: " + data.status; // line of error
    }
```

} else {

**EDIT**
I restored a backup of 6 months ago and it is still giving the same error and i know it worked then. So something in IIS or the server has changed. Thanks for the help

Comment: An error is great, but without seeing the code that produces it we can't help.

Comment: Please post extracts from the source files `WaterReadingCapture:1291` and `jquery.jqGrid.src.js:7572`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this quite a while back. Problem was that IIS was not sending detailed errors. Dont no how the option changed from Detailed errors to Detailed errors for local requests and custom error pages for remote requests on the Error Pages module in IIS. Changed it back to detailed errors and working ever since.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in the implementation of `errorTextFormat` which you use. The `data` parameter is `jqXHR` object, which is a superset of the `XMLHTTPRequest` object. Both supports [getResponseHeader](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-getresponseheader%28%29-method) method which you can use to detect whether the response from the server contains JSON data or it's HTML data. So you can test something like

```js
errorTextFormat: function (data) {
    var contentType = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
    if (typeof contentType === string &&
            contentType.split(";")[0] === "application/json") {
        // you can use $.parseJSON(data.responseText) here
        return '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" ' +
           'style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>' +
           "<strong>" + $.parseJSON(data.responseText).Message + "<strong>";
    }
    return data.responseText;
}
```

I used `contentType.split(";")[0]` because the "Content-Type" header can be either `"application/json; charset=utf-8"` or `"application/json"`.

Comment: I am getting a response back now but now displays a html page within the dialog form saying "500 - Internal Server Error". What could this be related to? It works fine on my local machine and the dev box that we use. And this used to work before. I am going to make a test site on prod and restore and restore the latest backup and then  work my way foward. Thanks for the help